# Is it possible to name a status effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to change the name or the icon of a status effect in minecraft. My goal is to give someone slowness. But I want the effect to have the name "Injured" or "Bleeding". Is this possible with command block or maybe texture pack or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes you can, using a resource pack.

The `assets/minecraft/lang` folder contains all the translations. The default language file is `en_us.json`. You can create your own in a resource pack and any lines you include will overwrite the vanilla lines.

```
{"effect.minecraft.slowness":"Bleeding"}
```

The textures for all status effects are stored in the file `assets/minecraft/textures/gui/container/inventory.png`. You can simply copy this file from the vanilla resource pack, modify the slowness texture, then include it in your resource pack.